# How to retrieve only id and name which is associated with platform mac only in json format by using python

Tags: python

In this list how to retrieve only name and id in JSON format by using python How to retrieve only id and name which is associated with platform mac only in json format by using python

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "id": "1",
    "platform": "windows",
    "total_ram": 12884,
    "last_ip_address": "123456789",
    "group_name": "c",
    "entity": "other",
    "last_seen": "2019-04-16T19:19:43+10:00"
  },
{
"name": "b",
    "id": "2",
    "platform": "mac",
    "total_ram": 1112884,
    "last_ip_address": "123456789",
    "group_name": "d",
    "entity": "other",
    "last_seen": "2019-04-16T19:19:43+10:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: If the list is named `data`, then `data[0]["name"]` will give you the name from the first dictonary. I leave getting the `id` as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop though your list of JSONs and extract the name and id. You can create a new list of dictionaries with them and finally convert the list of dictionaries back to JSON.

```
import json

finallist = []
for i in X:
  result = {
      "name": i['name'],
      "id": i['id']
  }
  finallist.append(result)

print(finallist) 
finalJSON = json.dumps(finallist)
print(finalJSON)
```

To get only certain platforms, example 'mac', you can use.

```
 import json
    
    finallist = []
    for i in X:
        if i['platform'] == 'mac':
            result = {
              "name": i['name'],
              "id": i['id']
            }
            finallist.append(result)
    
    print(finallist) 
    finalJSON = json.dumps(finallist)
    print(finalJSON)
```

Comment: You still need to loop through all JSON entries but before appending the result to the 'finallist', check if i.['platform'] == 'mac' so only those entries/records are appended into the final list.

Comment: See modified answer

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is

```
newdata = []
for row in data:
    newdata.append( {'name': row['name'], 'id': row['id'] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary comprehension that only inserts a key-value pair into a new dictionary if its key is inside a tuple (in this case, `('name', 'id')`):

```
data = [...]
result = [{k: v for k, v in item.items() if k in ('name', 'id')} for item in data]
```